# Getting updated value from dropdownlist inside updatepanel into jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

Using ASP.Net/JQuery
I have a dropdownlist inside an updatepanel. When the value of the dropdownlist changes and an asynchronous postback is made, how do I then update a variable in my jquery function with the new value of the dropdownlist?

I'm having a hard time getting the new value from the dropdownlist into the jquery function, it only picks up the previously selected value.

inside the pre_render, we are registering the script.

Thanks

TR

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
var selectedText = $('#ddlTest option:selected').text();
   alert(selectedText);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

when your code-behind is completed after the dropdown list has been changed, you need to deliver some js to the client-side using [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx). This way you can get any values you want back to your client side scripts.

Seeing some code would help :)